# Unable to run through MVC external login example

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ssl, oauth, ssl-certificate

This has me feeling pretty lame. I'm trying to learn how to do the 'oAuth2 dance' and in order to see it working i wanted to get a trivial demo site up and running and logging in via twitter. i've seen a demo where it's as easy as creating a new web mvc project, making sure 'individual user accounts' is the auth mode, and un-commenting the two auto-generated lines to enable twitter auth in Startup.Auth.cs. i should then be able to hit the login page of the *completely* stock, boilerplate web project, and click the 'Twitter' button that's now visible under "Use another service to log in."

however, when i do this - unlike the demo i saw - i get a certificate error:

> The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
>   Exception Details: System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Now, i don't claim to deeply understand how certs work, but i've checked and i have a certificate for 'localhost' and i've verified it as being associated with my user account and the computer account user the cert mgr tool in MMC (it even reads 'IIS Express Development Certificate'). i also see 'localhost' under 'trusted root cert authorities'.

i immediately don't know what else to check...i'm not even 100% sure that it's complaining about *my* localhost cert (as opposed to that of twitter?); i'm not even sure what server address the internals of the Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter code is trying to hit?...

One thing i noticed while looking at my user certs is that were a bunch that seemed to be installed by fiddler that were issued by 'DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot', including one for localhost. I tried to disable this cert, however, and didn't make any difference. i can't imagine installing fiddler would so thoroughly disable your system configuration, anyway. that said, i 've tried it with and without fiddler running and nothing works.

what could possibly be causing this? i still have a lot to get done and i'm stuck in the starting gate. i feel ridiculous that i can't even get auto-generated MS sample code to run on my machine....argh.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered your site to Twitter as well as obtain an app secret/key? Refer to this to get your answers.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services#TWITTER.